# Error in creating object of Class A with named variable A

Tags: typescript

I have below class

```
export class TechnicalContactInfo {
    constructor(){
       this.Communication = [];
    }
/** @description ContactFunctionCode */PER01;
/** @description ContactName */PER02;
/** @description Communication */Communication: Communication[];
}
```

When i trying to create object of it as below

```
var TechnicalContactInfo:TechnicalContactInfo = new TechnicalContactInfo();
```

it is giving me error as below

> [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature.

Can someone help me to find why ?

Comment: The variable name is the same as the class name. Change it and I expect it will work.

Comment: yes it is working now.. thanks. May i know why it is happening ?

Comment: Answer was a bit long for comments so I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by the fact that you name the variable the same as the class. If we look at how a class is down-compiled to `ES5`, it may be a bit more obvious why the class declaration and the variable declaration cause a conflict:

```
var TechnicalContactInfo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TechnicalContactInfo() {
    }
    return TechnicalContactInfo;
}());
var TechnicalContactInfo = new TechnicalContactInfo();
```

You can't define the `TechnicalContactInfo` because there already is a variable named `TechnicalContactInfo` holding the class constructor function. While for ES6 we can use the class syntax the same holds true, variables and classes share the current naming scope, and if you define a variable and a class with the same name you will get into problems.